# Pandas Categorical not sorted by sort_values on different machines

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

**edit:** The core of the issue seems to be the newer pandas versions. If anybody knows code which does the same, but works with current pandas version, feel free to comment/answer below. Thanks.

I have a pandas dataframe called outputframe which has shirts in it with their corresponding sizes. The ordering of the sizes must be in the actual sizes order, not an alphabetical order. I solved this problem a while ago by using the following code:

```
def getSizeTable():
    return ['S','M','L','XL']
[...]
outputframe['size'] = pd.Categorical(outputframe['size'], getSizeTalbe()]
[...]
outputframe.sort_values(by=['productid','size'], ascending=True,inplace=True)
```

A few days ago I discovered that the code does not work on certain newer machines. The outputframe is sorted by productids, but the sizes are in their original order and not in the order from the categorical.

It doesn't work on my homeoffice computer and a fresh ubuntu installation at work. However, it does still work on an older windows 7 computer at work. All three computers use python27 and have the same packages installed (via miniconda).

I have looked through stackoverflow and pandas patchnotes but I couldn't find a solution to my problem nor alternative code which does the same thing. Categoricals seems the way to go. Does anybody know which different machines handle these Categorical differently? Is there an alternative line of code which accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: Same `pandas` version?

Comment: @AndrewL I double checked and it is not the same version. The working version is 17.x and the not-working version is 19.x. Now the question is: which change did invalidate my code and how can I fix it without downgrading the pandas version?

Comment: @bkd, if this problem is crucial - you could always use `virtualenv` to create virtual environments so that you can have this certain program work on pandas version 17.x without downgrading the version on your entire machine(s).

Comment: I'm wondering if defining categories in 17 implies a sort order. Have you tried setting `ordered = True` in 19? This may fix your issue.

Comment: @AndrewL I tried "ordered=True" after studying the pandas changelogs, but it didn't change the outcome :(

Comment: @MattR the problem with a conda/virtual env is that the script is part of a larger package and only this script requires this functionality. I'd have to separate the script into its own repo etc. I am trying to avoid that if possible, but jeah: the bug is crucial/blocking for our production team.

Comment: @bkd, a quick, but "painful", fix would be to create the virtualenv and just save the other scripts there as well.